# Notification of G Suite super admin user activity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam, google-identity, google-cloud-identity

Overview:

We have multiple super admin users configured in Google Cloud Identity and its integrated with company AD. I want to set up activity notification for G Suite super admin users.

Requirement:

if any super admin user logs in and does any activity that has to be logged and sent to other super admins over email.

Question:

Does Google Identity Platform have an inbuilt mechanism to capture super admin activity and send it as a notification?

if the above answer is "no" then does Google Identity Platform has an API to fetch super admin user activity?

Comment: Could you please clarify what does it have to do with gsuite-addons?

Comment: removed gsuite-addons tag.. Its question for gsuite identity

Comment: Tejas, no worries - just that the system works the way that you lose visibility when tagging incorrectly (that said, it is not the best system). Re:your question: you would probably want to look into [GSuite Admin SDK APIs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk) - I can't answer you right off the bat, but usually GSuite admin management is done via this SDK